# How to allow internet access to a website hosted on Windows server 2008 R2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, iis-7

I have hosted a website on Windows Server 2008 R2 and my website has some external links. The internet access is available on the server but my website is not getting internet access.

Firewall is turned off.
All Outbound and Inbound rules have exception for the website's port

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say based on your info, but sounds like you need to look at your router settings and allow traffic for your server through port 80

Does your site work on your home network if you browse to http://server.ip.address

Your server should ideally have a static up on your network